# Values replacement in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, regex, lambda, replace

I need to replace each cell containing values like number1(number2) with number2 (the value inside the parenthesis). For example: 56(3) -> 3, 33(5) -> 5

These values can appear in different columns.

The problem is that with pandas function

```
df.replace(to_replace=..., value=...)
```

i cannot use as `value` something that depends on the string matched.

I was trying something like:

```
df.replace(to_replace='[0-9]+([0-9]+)', value=lambda x: int(x.split("(")[1].strip(")")), regex=True)
```

But the `lambda` function doesn't work. Suggestions?

Comment: Try `df.replace(to_replace='^\d+\((\d+)\)$', value=r'\1', regex=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried df.apply instead?

A caveat is that using `apply` on a dataFrame sends the entire row as input to the lambda function, so you will have to do something like this:

```py
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(<insert lambda function here>)
```